# Reachable state space of an 8-puzzle

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I've just began studying Artificial Intelligence and am wondering why the reachable state space of an 8-puzzle is $9!/2$. I see that the number of permutations of the tiles is $9!$ but it is not immediately obvious why half the possible states of the puzzle are unreachable at any given state. Can anyone elaborate?

*An image of an 8-puzzle for reference with a random configuration on the left and the goal state on the right:*

[image: Sample 8-puzzle]

Comment: Because the state graph consists of two disconnected components of equal size (the total number of permutation inversions of every state is invariant modulo 2, so two states that have a total number of permutation inversions odd and even are not connected); I didn't find a well explained example, but [this presentation should be clear enough to let you understand it](http://ai.stanford.edu/~latombe/cs121/2011/slides/B-search-problems.ppt) (except the typo "connected" that should be replaced with "disconnected")

Comment: @Vor turn into an answer?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is an expansion of [this presentation](http://ai.stanford.edu/~latombe/cs121/2011/slides/B-search-problems.ppt).

Because the state graph consists of two disconnected components of equal size.
Without loss of generality we can  assume that the *target state* is $1\;2\;3\;...\;15\;\Box$.

```
 1  2  3  4
 5  6  7  8
 9 10 11 12
13 14 15  *
```

Given a state $S$ a *permutation inversion* is a tile $T_i$ that is placed after $T_j$ but $i < j$; this happens when (a) $T_i$ is in the same row of $T_j$, but on its right, or (b) $T_i$ is in a lower row:

```
 .  .  .  .      .  .  .  .
 3  .  .  1      .  7  .  .
 .  .  .  .      .  5  .  .
 .  .  .  .      .  .  .  .
    (a)             (b)
```

We define $N_j$ as the number of tiles $T_i$, $i < j$ that appears after $T_j$.
For example, in the state:

```
 1  2  3  4
 5 10  7  8
 9  6 11 12
13 14 15  *
```

we have that after $T_{7}$ there is one tile ($T_6$) that should be before it, so $N_7=1$; after $T_{10}$ there are four tiles ($T_7, T_8, T_9, T_6$) that should be before it, so $N_{10}=4$.

Let $N$ be the sum of all $N_i$ and the row number of the empty tile $T_{\Box}$

$$N = \sum_{i=1}^{15} N_i + row(T_{\Box})$$

In the example above we have: $N = N_7 + N_8 + N_9 + N_{10} + row(T_{\Box}) = 1 + 1 +1 + 4 + 4=11$

We can notice that when the empty tile is moved *horizontally* $N$ doesn't change; if we move the empty tile *vertically* $N$ changes by an even quantity.

For example:

```
 .  .  .  .      .  .  .  .
 .  .  2  3      .  .  *  3
 4  5  *  .      4  5  2  .
 .  .  .  .      .  .  .  .
```

$N' = N + 3 \mbox{ (2 is placed after 3,4,5)} - 1 \mbox{ (empty tile is moved up)} = N + 2$

```
 .  .  .  .      .  .  .  .
 .  .  *  4      .  .  3  4
 2  5  3  .      2  5  *  .
 .  .  .  .      .  .  .  .
```

$N' = N + 1 \mbox{ (2 is placed after 3)} - 2 \mbox{ (4,5 are placed after 3)} + 1 \mbox{ (empty tile is moved down)} = N$

So $N \bmod 2$ is *invariant under any legal move of the empty tile*.

We can conclude that the state space is split in two *disconnected* halves, one having $N \bmod = 0$ and the other having $N \mod 2 = 1$.

For example the following two states are not connected:

```
 1  2  3  4     1  2  3  4
 5  6  7  8     5  6  7  8
 9 10 11 12     9 10 11 12
13 14 15  *    13 15 14  *  
    N = 4         N = 5
```

Comment: This is the case for a 15-puzzle but it seems that the result can be generalized for an 8-puzzle as well. Thanks!

Comment: Those are great slides. Does it belong to some university course? Am interested to have a look at other related slides from same course / instructor. Can you point me to them?

Comment: @RajS: sorry, I found them on internet, I don't know the author.